# gspread - Performance of reading spreadsheet

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread

I log in to Google Sheets on program startup:

```
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(*args)
gs = gspread.authorize(credentials).open('My Sheets')
```

Then run a get-all command as part of an hourly callback:

```
sheets = {w.title: w.get_all_values() for w in gs.worksheets()}
```

The get-all line takes ~30 seconds for a midsize sheet (800kB as exported xlsx). Is there a better way to pull all the data, or is this a limit of running that much data through Google's API?

Comment: How about this? After it downloaded the spreadsheet as a excel file, it retrieves data. If the spreadsheet is continued to update on Google Drive, it removes the excel file after the data was retrieved. It will be done less than 30 s. If the spreadsheet is published, you can download it soon. If the spreadsheet cannot be published, you can download it using Drive API after you got access token.

Comment: Downloading as an excel file is an interesting option. It would be significantly faster, although not the most elegant way to use gspread. I'll implement it and do some benchmarking. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. IF you want to handle data using Python, for example, it handles data on spreadsheet using gspread on Google Drive, and only when it retrieves the large data, it retrieves the data from Google drive by Python's "require" using "GET". This can be carried out on just Python. How about this method?

Comment: That's what I'm thinking. I'll use the requests library to send a GET request for the compiled file.